# Syntax Highlighting While Running MATLAB via Terminal?

Tags: matlab, syntax

I really dislike the MATLAB GUI, thus, I followed some instructions online to open MATLAB via Terminal using `matlab -nodesktop`. It works. However, I lack the conveniences of syntax highlighting; the sorts that exists in vim, for example.

I am interested in knowing if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this FileExchange submissions:

- [Highlighting Matlab files in Vim](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28240)
- [Editing Matlab files in Vim](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21798-editing-matlab-files-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

There's [Matlab mode for emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/MatlabMode), and also a built-in octave mode which will serve for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `edit yourfile.m` in the terminal to open the matlab editor. This will open the editor without the entire matlab gui. Not sure why you'd want to do this though...